# Remove navigation bar in net maui

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I want to remove the navigation bar from the top, but I haven't been able to, this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage  NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Encuestadefensoria1.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Encuestadefensoria1"
            >
    

    <AbsoluteLayout>
```

```
<AbsoluteLayout>`
```

y este es el CS

```
sing System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using System.Globalization;





namespace x;

public  partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AppShell.SetNavBarIsVisible(this, false);

    }
```

I tried everything I read about this, but nothing worked for me, help

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you want to have the navigation pages displayed without the navigation bar.

[image: with and without Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"]

---

When I have needed to do this, it works for me to set the `Shell.NavBarIsVisible` property up front in the **AppShell.xaml** file. I see you have tried to set this in the `MainPage` constructor. See if it works if you do this instead.

```xml
<Shell
    x:Class="Encuestadefensoria1.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Encuestadefensoria1"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
    
</Shell>
```

---

I tested this just now with the default MAUI project (without modifying MainPage or anything else). It seems to do the trick in the build for Android and Windows Machine.

Answer (score 1):

On each page where you don't want to see the `navigation bar`, add the following code

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```

to your `content page` right after,

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Encuestadefensoria1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the title bar, simply clear the title, e.g. `<ContentPage Title="">` and that will make the title bar disappear.