# .NET MAUI: How to change font for Title or remove it?

Tags: maui

I have got a MAUI app that I have built on the default MAUI app. It has got a very large title bar that I want to be smaller or remove completely. So how can I change the Font, Margin, Padding of this MAUI App title bar in the default app? I mean that app, that is created when I create a new MAUI app in "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.5.3".

I found the text "Home" and I can change that text. But I find no way to change its font or margin or padding. When I try to add `FontSize` or `Margin` or `Padding` to the `ShellContent`, VS says these properties are not found in `ShellContent`.
I can add `IsVisible="False"` to the `ShellContent` and VS does not complain immediately, but then the app crashes immediately at startup with a null reference exception.

The following is the `AppShell.xaml` which defines the title `"Home"` and which is completely created by VS. I am quite new to MAUI, and I hope that I'm overlooking something very basic.

Alternatively, it would be very helpful if I could change the Title text from code behind. I *can* set the `AppShell`'s `Title` property from code behind, but that doesn't change what is shown in the title bar :-(       Also, I *can* change the `AppShell`'s child `ShellItem`'s `Title` from code beind, but that also doesn't change what is shown in the title bar :-(

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp2.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp2"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has two parts:

> How to change font for Title

For font appearance, you can try experimenting with the layout in the `Shell.TitleView` property. This example uses a `Label`, but you could also make a `HorizontalStackLayout` here if (for example) you wanted to add some icons to provide the functionality of a toolbar.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="untarget_windows.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:untarget_windows"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Label
            Text="Hello World "
            TextColor="Azure"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Padding="25,0,0,0"
            HeightRequest="50"
            FontAttributes="Italic"
            FontSize="Small" />
    </Shell.TitleView>
    <ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
</Shell>
```

[image: modified title bar]

---

The second part of your question is:

> ... or remove it?

One way to remove it for the entire app is to set the `Shell.NavBarIsVisible` property to `False` in **AppShell.xaml** (see full thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77646340/5438626))

```xml
<Shell
    .
    .
    .
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
```

Comment: This helps in so far, as I can use and set the Label in the TitleView from code behind. And I can indeed change the title's font. But my real problem, that the title bar takes too much space, is not solved by this. Nor your TitleView nor the Label inside do react to HeightRequest and even with an 8 point font, this bar stays the same old size.

Comment: If you'd prefer to remove the title bar there are answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77646340)

Comment: The entry you linked to on how to remove the title bar really solves my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear things are moving forward! I improved my answer by adding this info so that 'both' parts of your question are addressed.